# JavaScript Clicker With LocalStorage System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I´m new in JavaScript and I have write a little Counter. Now  I will save the clicks with LocalStorage and open the data when I start the Site.
It also works but when I reload the page the number of the variable is not counted to it when I trigger the onClick function rather the number is always attached to the variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var clicks = 0;

    function datenAbrufen() {
      clicks = localStorage.getItem("aktuelleKlicks");
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }

    function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
        datenSpeichern();
    };

    function datenSpeichern() {
        localStorage.setItem("aktuelleKlicks", clicks);
    };

    function trash() {
      clicks = -1;
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where/how do you call `datenAbrufen`? `onClick`?

Comment: `<body onload="datenAbrufen()">` and `<div id="fullpage" onClick="onClick()">` @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you call `datenAbrufen` on page load and `onClick`, er, on a click.

If so, the problem is in `datenAbrufen`: `localStorage` stores **strings**. So `clicks = localStorage.getItem("aktuelleKlicks");` sets `clicks` to a string. `clicks += 1` will then *append* the digit 1 to the end of the string. (On the first page load, `clicks` will get set to `null`. It works in that case because `clicks += 1` when `clicks` is `null` ends up being `1`, because `+=` will coerce `null` to `0`. `+` [and thus `+=`] wants either a number or a string; when `clicks` is a string, it does string concatenation; if `clicks` is a number, it does addition; otherwise, it does coercion, which depends on what it's coercing from. `null` coerces to `0` in that case.)

You need to parse the string into a number:

```
function datenAbrufen() {
  clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("aktuelleKlicks"), 10) || 0; // ***
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

`parseInt` will parse the string using the given number base (10 = decimal). If it can't, it will return `NaN`, so `|| 0` after it will take `0` if the number in local storage is invalid.

Live Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dfonxrtq/ (sadly, Stack Snippets don't allow local storage)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage stores data as strings and if you try to add something to a string you do "string addition" which is actually concatenation.
What you want to do is [convert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the data you read from localStorage back to a number.

```
clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("aktuelleKlicks"), 10);
```